# Склонение слова рубль в php

Tags: php

1 - рубль
2 - рубля
3 - рубля
4 -  рубля
5 - рублей
6 - рублей
7 - рублей
8 - рублей
9 - рублей
10 - рублей
11 - рублей
12 - рублей
13 - рублей
14 - рублей
15 - рублей
16 - рублей
17 - рублей
18 - рублей
19 - рублей
20 - рублей
21 - рубль
22 - рубля
23 - рубля
24 - рубля
25 - рублей

Мне нужно сделать баланс на сайте и чтобы слово рубль склонялось автоматически в зависимости от числа.
Я посмотрел до 10 числа и понял что если 2,3 и 4 окончание у числа то пишется рубля. Но когда дошел 12 понял что это не так. 
Помогите написать функцию...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function num2word($num = 0, $words = array())
{
    $num     = (int) $num;
    $cases   = array(2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2);
    return $num . ' ' . $words[($num % 100 > 4 && $num % 100 < 20) ? 2 : $cases[min($num % 10, 5)]];
}

echo num2word(23, ['рубль', 'рубля', 'рублей']);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function num2word(int $num, array $words): string
{
    $num = ($n = abs($num) % 100) > 19 ? $n % 10 : $n;

    switch ($num) {
        case 1:
            $w = $words[0];
            break;

        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 4:
            $w = $words[1];
            break;

        default: 
            $w = $words[2];
            break;
    }

    return $w;
}

echo num2word(23, ['рубль', 'рубля', 'рублей']).PHP_EOL;
echo num2word(151, ['рубль', 'рубля', 'рублей']).PHP_EOL;
echo num2word(556, ['рубль', 'рубля', 'рублей']).PHP_EOL;
```

https://3v4l.org/Wh6ki

Comment: А можешь прокомментировать код ? В чем фишка и как это работает ? Чтобы в дальнейшем я знал. Зачем остаток от ста и число 19 тут при чем...

Comment: Это функция склонения `num2word(23, ['рубль', 'рубля', 'рублей']);` первый параметр само число, второй параметр значения массива для склонения. `% 100` - означает, что берем две последние цифры от самого значения. Далее проверяем, если число больше 19, то получаем его последнюю цифру - `% 10` и далее проверяем уже через `switch`, если последняя цифра 1 то рубль, если из диапазона 2-4 - то рубля, в остальных случаях рублей.

Comment: Почему именно 19 ?

Comment: @cr1gger Основа алгоритма - смотрит на последнюю цифры и по ней определяем окончаение, например если `1` то `рубль`, это обосновано из-за произношения, `один`, `двадцать ОДИН`, `тридцать ОДИН` и т.д. Что я пропустил? правильно, промежуток от `11 до 19` мы читаем по другому, мы произносим не `десять ОДИН` а `одиннадцать`, не `десять два` а `двенадцать`, собсна отсюда и это проверка.

Comment: @cr1gger относительно алгоритма, у нас есть 3 слова `'рубль', 'рубля', 'рублей'` из них, `'рубль', 'рубля'` мы используем, только в случаях, когда на конце `1,2,3,4`, Остальное - `рублей`. Наш промежуток, как раз должен попадать под третье слово, но например у `12` на конце-то 2, чтобы попадал он в третье слово надо просто не смотреть его последнюю цифру, тогда число `12` попадает под `default`, а если бы брали только окончание, попадало-бы под `case 2:`

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * * Склонения
 * @param {Number} $count количество
 * @param {Array} $textForms варианты склонений [для одного, для двух-четырёх, больше четырёх]
 * @return string
 */
function decl($count, $textForms) {
    $count =abs($count) % 100;

    if ($count > 10 && $count < 20) {
        return $textForms[2];
    }

    $count = $count % 10;
    if ($count > 1 && $count < 5) {
        return $textForms[1];
    }

    if ($count === 1) {
        return $textForms[0];
    }

    return $textForms[2];
}

echo decl(2, ['рубль', 'рубля', 'рублей']);
echo decl(-12, ['рубль', 'рубля', 'рублей']);
echo decl(22, ['рубль', 'рубля', 'рублей']);
echo decl(32, ['рубль', 'рубля', 'рублей']);
```